# Issue running query in Google Collab + Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've followed the step by step here and inserted this snippet:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#snippetFileIds=%2Fv2%2Fexternal%2Fnotebooks%2Fsnippets%2Fbigquery.ipynb&snippetQuery=Using%20BigQuery%20with%20Pandas%20API

however, i can run the query, but then appears an error :

```html
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b9e37aa67e26> in <module>()
      9     COUNT(*) as total
     10   FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
---> 11 ''', project_id=project_id).total[0]
     12 
     13 df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(f'''

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.RecordBatch.from_arrays()

TypeError: from_arrays() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I have tried with several database, with no success.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed steps from Using BigQuery with Pandas API [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/bigquery.ipynb) and it works fine for me. 
Firstly you need to create Cloud Platform project if you not already have one, and then enable billing and BigQuery API.

When running first snippet of code, you need to click on a link, that shows in a console, copy verification code and paste it to the console in `Enter verification code` field:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Before running second snippet of code, you need to change the name of `project_id` field to the name of your actual project, that you created in GCP:

```
import pandas as pd

# https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects
project_id = 'your Cloud Platform project ID'
sample_count = 2000

row_count = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq('''
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
''', project_id=project_id).total[0]

df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(f'''
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
  WHERE RAND() < {sample_count}/{row_count}
''', project_id=project_id)

print(f'Full dataset has {row_count} rows')
```

After that, you will get following output:

[image]

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Muscat, I've created a new collab and it worked without issue ... 
Don't know what happened in the first !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating to the latest version of arrow 
`!pip install pyarrow==0.17.1`